# 1]Change variable value during script is running 2] while running Script in loop does not update variable value in workspace

Tags: matlab, serial-port, simulink, modbus

I am controlling a pilot plant of boiler through Matlab using modbus RTU (serial communication).

I am running my control program (in editor) for 45 mins through a loop but I am facing two problems :

1] I can't change any variable value while running program which is deadly needed.

2] I am unable to see real time data in workspace while running script.

It updates all variables after finishing execution time. For my application I want data to appear for every iteration.

I couldn't solve them so I switched to simulink but that was even more frustrating.

In simulink I used user defined blocks (embedded Matlab function) to generate modbus address PDU which does not support to in-built matlab functions (like dec2hex).

Will please someone let me know in simulink, serial send/receive support which data format?(ASCII/HEX/DEC)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the status of your system after each iteration this can be solved by putting a breakpoint there. If required you can even change the value of variables then.